# [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ExpoBackgroundFetch.default.registerTaskAsync')]

Tags: react-native, expo

[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ExpoBackgroundFetch.default.registerTaskAsync')]

I am getting this error trying to registerTaskAsync in the following code

```js
async function initBackgroundFetch(taskName,
  taskFn,
  interval = 60 * 15) {
  try {
    if (!TaskManager.isTaskDefined(taskName)) {
      TaskManager.defineTask(taskName, taskFn);
    }
    const options = {
      minimumInterval: interval // in seconds
    };
    await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(taskName, options);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("registerTaskAsync() failed:", err);
  }
}

initBackgroundFetch('myTaskName', myTask, 5)
```

I am not able to find what's wrong with it

Expecting The asyncTask to register and execute

Comment: Could you show your imports or full code example?

Comment: import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';


import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';

Comment: did you find these libraries in the node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes but it's red i don't know if there is error related

Comment: the error `undefined is not an object` for imports related to building processes. Did you use EAS?

Comment: Yes i am using EAS

Comment: Try to create the beta build. I guess your system did not apply native code after installing these libraries.

Comment: I have same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: Try removing the node_modules folder and retry installing with npm install ---legacy-peer-deps. if you see your package red there is a problem with it.